# Plotting a data.frame in R

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

i'm new to R and i need advise in plotting a dataframe in R which looks like this:

```
         V1          V2         V3          V4         
          1       Mazda     Toyota     Peugeot
   Car1.txt 0,507778837 0,19834711 0,146892655
   Car2.txt 0,908717802 0,64214047 0,396508728
```

i would like to plot this dataframe ( which in fact has 7 columns and 95 rows) 
in a single graph, where v2, v3, v4 represent a line in a different color and named like the car names , V1 as label of the x-axis, whereas the y-axis is in the range[0,1].

I have really no clue how to do this, so i'm very thankful for any advice

Comment: Have you take a look [R Introduction](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html)? There is section about graphics. But for start check import data section cause it looks for me like your data wasn't proper read into R. And welcome on StackOverflow ;)

Comment: To get started, have a look at the R introduction manual, chapter 12: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Answer (score 8):

The doctor prescribes a slight modification to Roman's data frame.

```
library(ggplot2)
my.cars <- data.frame(
  Toyota = runif(50), 
  Mazda = runif(50), 
  Renault = runif(50),
  Car = paste("Car", 1:50, ".txt", sep = "")  
)

my.cars.melted <- melt(my.cars, id.vars = "Car")
```

He then suggests that it looks like the car variable is categorical, so your first choice would be a barchart.

```
p_bar <- ggplot(my.cars.melted, aes(Car, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
p_bar
```

He then notes that for 95 cars, this could get a bit cumbersome.  Perhaps a dotplot would be more suitable.

```
p_dot <- ggplot(my.cars.melted, aes(Car, value, col = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle = 90))
p_dot
```

As this is still a little tricky to get useful information out of, it might be best to order the cars by the average value (whatever value means)

```
my.cars.melted$Car <- with(my.cars.melted, reorder(Car, value))
```

(Then redraw `p_dot` as before.)

Finally, the doctor notes that you can draw the line plot that Roman recommended with

```
p_lines <- ggplot(my.cars.melted, aes(as.numeric(Car), value, col = variable)) +
  geom_line()
p_lines
```

Comment: `melt` needs `library(reshape)`.

Answer (score 5):

This should get you started.

```
my.cars <- data.frame(Toyota = runif(50), Mazda = runif(50), Renault = runif(50)) #make some fake data for this example
plot(x = 1:nrow(my.cars), y = my.cars$Toyota, type = "n") #make an empty plot
with(my.cars, lines(x = 1:nrow(my.cars), y = Toyota, col = "red")) #add lines for Toyota
with(my.cars, lines(x = 1:nrow(my.cars), y = Mazda, col = "red")) # add lines for Mazda
with(my.cars, lines(x = 1:nrow(my.cars), y = Renault, col = "navy blue")) # add lines for Renault
```

I used `with()` so that you don't have to type `my.cars$Toyota`, `my.cars$Mazda`... every time you want to call a column. Explore `?par` for further parameters that can be passed to `plot`. A doctor with a ggplot2 solution will see you shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe cannot be constucted as in the example so I am modifying slightly:

```
tcars <- read.table(textConnection(" V1       Mazda     Toyota     Peugeot
    Car1.txt 0,507778837 0,19834711 0,146892655
    Car2.txt 0,908717802 0,64214047 0,396508728", header=TRUE, dec=",")
 # need to use dec arg with commas as decimal points!
 tcars
        V1     Mazda    Toyota   Peugeot
1 Car1.txt 0.5077788 0.1983471 0.1468927
2 Car2.txt 0.9087178 0.6421405 0.3965087

 matplot(data.matrix(tcars[-1]), type="b", xaxt="n")
 axis(1, labels=tcars[[1]],at=1:NROW(tcars))
```

[Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9nei.png)